# From Silverlight to Blazor: How to keep using current RIA Seivices

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, blazor

I need to update a current application written in Silverlight + RIA Services. The idea is to replace the Silverlight client by a Blazor client.

Is there a possibility that we write a new Blazor-base client app and consume the current available RIA Services?

If yes, will the RIA Services be called directly from the client Blazor app or it would be better to do that in the server side (aspnet core)?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, that's not feasible. The blazor-base client cannot invoke the WCF RIA service. This is because of the framework. The dotnetcore-based blazor client does not always invoke the old WCF service. There are some problems left over from history. I recommend that you use the RESTAPI to refactor the current service project, and as you mentioned, the server is built using CORE WEBAPI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: https://opensilver.net/ does exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

the short answer is yes.
the WCF Ria services has next version called [OpenRiaServices](https://github.com/OpenRIAServices/OpenRiaServices).

you can use [this sample](https://github.com/caicainiao/OpenRiaPlayground) to add http binding for xamarin and blazor clients.

Comment: Can you point out the Blazor binding?  Everything there seems to be > 3 years old. And the core lib is on CodePlex?

Comment: Sample defined for xamarin platform, so you can use it for blazor. Last versio of OpenRiaServices released on Dec 4, 2019. not 3 years ago. use version 5 preview. I use it on blazor and it works like charm.source code is on github https://github.com/OpenRIAServices/OpenRiaServices

Comment: "I use it on blazor ..." leaves the question: Blazor/Wasm or Blazor/Server?

Comment: Blazor webassembly